# How to get the source component during dragEnter in Java SWT

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt

I would like to create the following workflow:

1. There are two types of boxes (A and B) and two types of baskets (C and D).
2. Both types of boxes can be dragged and dropped into based C.
3. But only boxes of type A can be dragged and dropped in D.

I would like to detect the type of box (A or B) during the dragEnter event in the DropTargetListener, so that I can change the cursor to DROP_NONE.

But right now all I can do is detect it during the actual drop event and then throw it away if it is incompatible with the basket.

Please guide me on how to solve this issue.

NOTE: I am using SWT org.eclipse.swt.dnd framework.

SNIPPET:

I would like to do something like this:

```
public void dragEnter (DropTargetEvent e)
{
    Box b = e.getSource // this is the part I need help with

    if(b.type == 'B')
       e.detail = DROP_NONE;
}
```

Comment: Rather than trying to get the source you could use different Transfer types - this is the usual way to validate drop data.

Comment: @greg-449 Oh ok, it turns out that that is indeed that best way to go forward from what I have read. If you could post an answer below with a idea of how to go about it. It would be great. Thank you sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a static variable to keep the current drag source.
You set it in `dragStart` and null it in `dragFinished`.
Then you use it in `dragEnter` and other events to make your evaluations.

Comment: That's ultimately what we ended up doing! Thanks for the answer Loris!